# Run operations in a group concurrently, but run then run batches of these operations serially

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Take these to enumeration loops. They enumerate an array of objects and save them. I want each of these to run concurrently, HOWEVER, I want to wait until all of the `categoriesMainToSave` return before starting on the `categoriesSubToSave` batch.

```
    // Save all the categories
    [categoriesMainToSave enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CategoryMain* main = (CategoryMain*)obj;
        [[BFClientAPI sharedAPI] createCategoryMain:main withSuccess:^{

        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@",error);

        }];

    }];

    [categoriesSubToSave enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CategorySub* sub = (CategorySub*)obj;
        [[BFClientAPI sharedAPI] createCategorySub:sub withSuccess:^{

        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@",error);

        }];

    }];
```

I started to try dispatch groups:

```
        dispatch_group_t groupMain = dispatch_group_create();

        [categoriesMainToSave enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            dispatch_group_enter(groupMain);
            CategoryMain* main = (CategoryMain*)obj;
            [[BFClientAPI sharedAPI] createCategoryMain:main withSuccess:^{
                dispatch_group_leave(groupMain);

            } failure:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
                dispatch_group_leave(groupMain);

            }];
        }];

        dispatch_group_notify(groupMain,dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            // Repeat dispatch_group pattern with categoriesSubToSave here
        });
```

But then I create a nested effect in `dispatch_group_notify`. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dispatch group is a good solution. If you don't want to nest your `categoriesSubToSave` work in the `dispatch_group_notify` block, you can use `dispatch_group_wait` instead:

```
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    for (CategoryMain *main in categoriesMainToSave) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [[BFClientAPI sharedAPI] createCategoryMain:main withSuccess:^{
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    // All mains are now saved or failed.

    for (CategorySub *sub in categoriesMainToSave) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [[BFClientAPI sharedAPI] createCategorySub:sub withSuccess:^{
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        } failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
            dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
    }

    dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    // All subs are now saved or failed.
```

However, if this code runs on the main thread, it's a very bad idea. You should use `dispatch_group_notify` if you're launching the saves from the main thread, or launch the saves from another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Try method with option to enumerate:

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts
                     usingBlock:(void (^)(id obj,
                                          NSUInteger idx,
                                          BOOL *stop))block
```

with [NSEnumerationConcurrent](http://goo.gl/lCn4rW) as option.

From documentation:

---

Specifies that the Block enumeration should be concurrent.

The order of invocation is nondeterministic and undefined; this flag is a hint and may be ignored by the implementation under some circumstances; the code of the Block must be safe against concurrent invocation.

---

**UPD**

If createCategoryMain is concurrent operation. You need synchronise many asynchronous operations. You can use NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. Operations let to make dependencies between operations. You can create list of operations, that will initialise categories from categoriesMainToSave (first group) and list of operations that will initialise categories from categoriesSubToSave (second group). Then you can make the dependencies between operations from second and first groups. And then add these operations to NSOperationsQueue. But I think, now you have very simple solution.

Comment: That's actually a great option I never knew about but since these are all async server operations with unknown return times then I still need some async queueing mechanism.